Why GDT is not working in the x86_64 System?
I want to enable GDT in x86_64 OS. I have written following codes to enable the GDT.
struct gdt_entry
{// 128 Bit
    uint16_t limit_low;       // Lower 16 bits of the segment limit
    uint16_t base_low;        // Lower 16 bits of the base address
    uint8_t base_middle;      // Next 8 bits of the base address
    uint8_t access;           // Access byte
    uint8_t granularity;      // Flags and upper limit
    uint8_t base_high;        // Next 8 bits of the base address
    uint32_t base_upper;      // Upper 32 bits of the base address
    uint32_t reserved;        // Reserved (must be zero)
} __attribute__((packed));
typedef struct gdt_entry gdt_entry_t;


// Structure for GDTR
struct gdtr {
    uint16_t limit;
    uint64_t base; // Use uint64_t for 64-bit systems
} __attribute__((packed));
typedef struct gdtr gdtr_t;

extern void gdt_flush(gdtr_t *gdtr_instance);
extern void reloadSegments();

gdt_entry_t gdt_entries[5];
gdtr_t gdtr_instance;

void gdt_setup( uint8_t idx, uint64_t base, uint32_t limit, uint8_t access, uint8_t granularity){
    gdt_entries[idx].limit_low    = limit & 0xFFFF;       // 16 bit
    gdt_entries[idx].base_low     = base  & 0xFFFF;       // 16 bit
    gdt_entries[idx].base_middle  = (base >> 16) & 0xFF;  // 8 bit
    gdt_entries[idx].access       = access;
    gdt_entries[idx].granularity  = (limit >> 16) & 0x0F; // Set limit : lower 4 bit
    gdt_entries[idx].granularity |= granularity & 0xF0;   // Set Flags : upper 4 bit
    gdt_entries[idx].base_high    = (base >> 24) & 0xFF;       // 8 bit
    gdt_entries[idx].base_upper   = (base >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF; // 32 bit
    gdt_entries[idx].reserved     = 0;                         // 32 bit
}


void init_gdt(){
    // index = 0, base = 0, limit = 0, access = 0, granularity = 0
    gdt_setup(0, 0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0);             // null descriptor selector : 0x0
    // index = 1, base = 0, limit = 0xFFFFFFFF, access = 0x9A = 154, granularity = 0xA0 = 160
    gdt_setup(1, 0, 0xFFFFF, 0x9A, 0xA0);    // kernel mode code segment, selector : 0x8

    // index = 2, base = 0, limit = 0xFFFFFFFF, access = 0x92 = 146, granularity = 0xA0 = 160
    gdt_setup(2, 0, 0xFFFFF, 0x92, 0xA0);    // kernel mode data segment, selector : 0x10

    // index = 3, base = 0, limit = 0xFFFFFFFF, access = 0xFA = 250, granularity = 0xA0 = 160
    gdt_setup(3, 0, 0xFFFFF, 0xFA, 0xA0);    // user mode code segment, selector : 0x18 

    // index = 4, base = 0, limit = 0xFFFFFFFF, access = 0xF2 = 242, granularity = 0xA0 = 160
    gdt_setup(4, 0, 0xFFFFF, 0xF2, 0xA0);    // user mode data segment, selector : 0x20

    // Calculate the GDT limit and base address
    gdtr_instance.limit = (uint16_t) (sizeof(gdt_entry_t) * 5 - 1);
    gdtr_instance.base = (uint64_t) &gdt_entries;

    gdt_flush((gdtr_t *) &gdtr_instance);
    reloadSegments();
}

To load GDT into GDTR register
section .text
global gdt_flush
gdt_flush:
   MOV RAX, [RDI] ;Getting gdtr_instance pointer from externel gdt.c 
   LGDT  [RAX]
   RET


global reloadSegments
reloadSegments:
   ; Reload CS register:
   PUSH 0x08                 ; Push code segment to stack, 0x08 is a stand-in for your code segment
   LEA RAX, [rel reload_CS]  ; Load address of reload_CS into RAX, LEA (Load Effective Address), 
   PUSH RAX                  ; Push this value to the stack
   LRETQ                     ; Perform a far return, RETFQ or LRETQ depending on syntax


reload_CS:
   ; Reload data segment registers
   MOV   AX, 0x10 ; 0x10 is a stand-in for your data segment
   MOV   DS, AX
   MOV   ES, AX
   MOV   FS, AX
   MOV   GS, AX
   MOV   SS, AX
   RET

The full code is in here.
reloadSegments function is causing the crash the system. I also checked GDB I have seen There is no 4th entry although I have entered gdt_setup(4, 0, 0xFFFFF, 0xF2, 0xA0); inside of init_gdt() function and also I have seen unnecessary 255th entry also present although I have used gdtr_instance.limit = (uint16_t) (sizeof(gdt_entry_t) * 5 - 1);.
I have seen following GDB output :
gdt_setup(idx=0 '\000', base=0, limit=0, access=0 '\000', granularity=0 '\000') at src/x86_64/gdt.c :19
gdt_setup(idx=255 '\377', base=18446603339441663968, limit=2147491364, access=255 '\377', granularity=119 'w') at src/x86_64/gdt.c :30
gdt_setup(idx=1 '\001', base=0, limit=4294967295, access=154 '\232', granularity=160 '\240') at src/x86_64/gdt.c :41
gdt_setup(idx=255 '\377', base=18446603339441663968, limit=2147491364, access=255 '\377', granularity=181 '\265') at src/x86_64/gdt.c :44
gdt_setup(idx=2 '\002', base=0, limit=4294967295, access=146 '\222', granularity=160 '\240') at src/x86_64/gdt.c :19
gdt_setup(idx=3 '\003', base=0, limit=4294967295, access=250 '\372', granularity=160 '\240') at src/x86_64/gdt.c :19
gdt_setup(idx=255 '\377', base=18446603339441663968, limit=2147491364, access=255 '\377', granularity=243 '\363') at src/x86_64/gdt.c :32


Qemu Log is showing Triple fault.
The Qemu log :
CPU Reset (CPU 0)
RAX=ffffffff80000010 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=00000000000000c0 RDX=0000000000000000
RSI=0000000000000000 RDI=ffffffff80006990 RBP=ffff8000bff36fe0 RSP=ffff8000bff36fc8
R8 =00000000000000c0 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=ffffffff80003445 RFL=00000082 [--S----] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0028 0000000000000000 00000000 00209b00 DPL=0 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0030 0000000000000000 00000000 00009300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
IDT=     0000000000000000 00000000
CR0=80010011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=00000000bff26000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=ffffffff8000694c CCD=ffffffff8000698c CCO=ADDQ
EFER=0000000000000d00
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM01=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM02=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM03=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM04=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM05=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM06=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM07=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM08=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM09=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM10=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM11=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM12=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM13=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
XMM14=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 XMM15=0000000000000000 0000000000000000
     7: v=03 e=0000 i=1 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
     8: v=0d e=001a i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xd
     9: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:00000000000efb0a pc=00000000000efb0a SP=0010:0000000000000fc8 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000f6106
EAX=000f6106 EBX=000f3e0a ECX=00000000 EDX=00000cf9
ESI=00000000 EDI=00100000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000fc8
EIP=000efb0a EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f6180 00000037
IDT=     000f61be 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=000f61c8 CCD=00009e34 CCO=SUBL
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd
Triple fault

I create gdt_entry structure from here.I don't understand what is causing the problem?
Do I not need the uint32_t base_upper; and uint32_t reserved; section in the gdt_entry_t structure what is causing the problem as it is remaining zero.
I need help to resolve the issue.
Edit : forum.osdev.org

@Michael Petch I have commited with latest update GitHub

I have found the previous Paging System was not working as my GDT has problem but now GDT is now creating crash after enable 64 bit GDT

gdt_flush looks weird.  LGDT should run with a gdtr_t (a limit+base) as its memory operand like lgdt [rel gdtr_instance] or lgdt [rdi] where RDI is &gdtr_instance, but you deref the pointer an extra time with mov rax, [rdi] / lgdt [rax].  Check where GDTR is actually pointing, e.g. with sgdt or with a debugger like Bochs's built-in debugger which can dump the emulated CPU's internal state and pretty-print GDT and page-table entries so you can more easily see that they're correct.

I made lgdt [rdi] but nothing changed

Probably has nothing to do with your problem but it's a bad idea to use the same base name for multiple modules (e.g. gdt.c and gdt.s) because both produce the same object file. BTW, your github is missing the limine stuff apparently. Also it's bad git use to have version directories instead of tags...

I have used $(NASM) $(NASM_FLAG) $(SRC_DIR)/x86_64/gdt.s -o $(BUILD_DIR)/gdt_s.o to generate two different object file gdt.o and gdt_s.o

Still bad practice, nobody expects gdt_s.o to be created from gdt.s. Also .s is typically used for gnu assembler. For nasm we use .asm  by convention. Anyway, as I said, unrelated to the problem.

okay thankyou for your comment I will update the repo with tag and change as u mentioned

But most importantly, what do I have to do to get it to build. fatal error: ../limine/limine.h: No such file or directory

In long mode GDT entries are 64-bit (8 bytes) EXCEPT for System Segments (LDT and TSS segments) which are 128 bits (16 bytes).

@Jester : oops. In this project you have to go into the x86_64/0.6/src  directory and do git clone https://github.com/limine-bootloader/limine.git --branch=v8.x-binary --depth=1 and then make -C limine . Then you can go back to the x86_64/0.6 directory and make the kernel.

I have made a pull request here:  https://github.com/baponkar/KeblaOS/pull/2  which fixes a bug in gdt_flush that causes the GDTR to be loaded from the wrong memory address; reloadSegments which uses the wrong instruction for a 64-bit FAR Return (use RETFQ); GDT entries are 8 byte (not 16-byte) except for TSS and LDT entries which are 16 byte (2 consecutive 8 byte GDT entries); Added a new function gdt_setup_sysseg that will create a system segment (for creating TSS and LDT entries); other minor fixes.

Thankyou @MichaelPetch and others for your valuable comments.

Based on the comments I received there were 3 problems that needed to be rectified.
gdt_flush was being passed a pointer to a GDT record (GDTR) but the code I wrote added an unnecessary de-reference that caused an invalid GDTR to be loaded.
gdt_flush:
   MOV RAX, [RDI] ;Getting gdtr_instance pointer from externel gdt.c 
   LGDT  [RAX]
   RET

had to be changed to:
gdt_flush:
   LGDT  [RDI]    ;First parameter (RDI) is the address of a GDTR.
   RET


My gdt_entry structure was 128 bits (16 bytes), however in long mode entries are still 64 bits (8 bytes) in size. An exception is that TSS and LDT system segments require 2 gdt_entry with the high 32-bits of the base in the second entry.
I changed my gdt_entry to be:
struct gdt_entry
{// 64-Bit not 128 Bit
    uint16_t limit_low;       // Lower 16 bits of the segment limit
    uint16_t base_low;        // Lower 16 bits of the base address
    uint8_t base_middle;      // Next 8 bits of the base address
    uint8_t access;           // Access byte
    uint8_t granularity;      // Flags and upper limit
    uint8_t base_high;        // Next 8 bits of the base address
} __attribute__((packed));
typedef struct gdt_entry gdt_entry_t;

I kept my function gdt_setup the same and created a gdt_setup_sysseg function that can be used to create GDT entries for the TSS and LDT system segment types. That function looks like:
// Version to create TSS and LDT entries which require 2 GDT entries
void gdt_setup_sysseg( uint8_t idx, uint64_t base, uint32_t limit, uint8_t access, uint8_t granularity){
    // First half of a system segment is the same as a regular segment
    gdt_setup(idx, base, limit, access, granularity);

    // Setup the following GDT entry with the upper 32 bits of the base and zero upper 32bits
    // that are reserved.
    gdt_setup(idx + 1, (base >> 48) & 0xffff , (base >> 32) & 0xffff, 0, 0);
}


I incorrectly used the nonexistent LRETQ instruction in NASM that was interpreted as a label. As a result no far return was generated and the things I pushed on the stack eventually caused an exception. I had to change the LRETQ to RETFQ in my reloadSegments function.

That only fixes one of your bugs. You also need to lgdt [rdi] instead of mov rax, [rdi] / lgdt [rax], which Michael Petch confirmed was also necessary.  (It wasn't sufficient on its own because of the entry-size bug, but that doesn't mean it wasn't a problem; it was just what I noticed from reading the question.)

@PeterCordes The LRETQ that should have been RETFQ was also a fatal bug that also had to be applied. NASM treated LRETQ as a label and never generated a ret of any kind so there was junk left on the stack that eventually caused an exception.. All three things had to be fixed for the code to work.
